# Xamarin Forms Build Failing: Missing dx.jar

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, sdk

I am trying to build a Xamarin Forms 3.4 solution but am getting the following compilation error:

```
Unable to access jarfile C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\32.0.0\\lib\dx.jar
```

The folder in question only contains the following files:

```
apksigner.jar
d8.jar
shrinkedAndroid.jar
```

I opened the Android SDK Manager and can't see any installed platforms or tools. I get the error:

```
Loading SDK component information failed. Please retry.
```

This solution built just fine last time I worked on it. I'm thinking of re-installing Xamarin but that feels a little dramatic.

Comment: You  can try to repair your visual studio  first. For more information, check [Repair Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) .

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Thanks, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: You can check if you have set up the [Android SDK for Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=windows) correctly .

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do: -

Open the Android SDK Manager with another version of Visual Studio (2022).

Go to Tools Tab > Android SDK Build Tools and uninstall the 32.0.0 version.

This will allow your project to pick another version with the dx.jar file. Install version 30.0.2 if you don't have it already.

Comment: Hi, how / where would you pick another version?